How to understand May's proof that counit map is a weak equivalence?
A similar question was asked about 4 years ago here, but received no answers, so I hope it is appropriate to post a new question. I am trying to read the singular homology section in May's Concise Course in Algebraic Topology. On page $124$ he claims that the counit map $\gamma: \Gamma X = |\text{Sing}(X)| \to X$ is a weak homotopy equivalence. He proves it on page $126$, but I have serious issues trying to follow the proof. The entire proof is also typed up in the linked question from four years ago.
The part that is particularly strange is his proof of injectivity. What is not clear to me is what he means by "We can then lift $h$ simplex by simplex to a simplicial map $\widetilde{h} \ldots$. How I understand it, we need to construct a lift $\widetilde{h}$ of $h$, which we could do if we knew that $\gamma$ is a Serre fibration, but this is an even more complicated result than what we are proving - it was shown to be true in this wonderful answer. So there must be something else May had in mind. Another extremely peculiar thing is that he doesn't explicitly use any property or definition of $\gamma$ whatsoever in his argument; so if his argument was to go through as I understand it, wouldn't it prove that absolutely any map is a fibration for simplicial complexes (and therefore all regular CW complexes)?

In saying this, May is not referring to some abstract lifting property like that of a Serre fibration, but to the concrete nature of $\gamma$. If $\Delta^n\rightarrow X$ is a map from the topological $n$-simplex, this gives rise to a simplicial map $\Delta^n\rightarrow\mathrm{Sing}(X)$ from the simplicial $n$-simplex and the composite of the geometric realization of this simplicial map and $\gamma$ is the original map. Now do this for each simplex to obtain the desired lift.
This is just the fact that $|-|\colon\mathbf{sSet}\rightleftarrows\mathbf{Top}\colon\mathrm{Sing}(-)$ is a pair of adjoint functors. Thus, if $S$ is a simplicial set and $X$ a space, a map $|S|\rightarrow X$ corresponds to a simplicial map $S\rightarrow\mathrm{Sing}(X)$. To go from the latter to the former, one takes the geometric realization $|S|\rightarrow|\mathrm{Sing}(X)|$ and then composes with the counit $|\mathrm{Sing}(X)|\rightarrow X$. And, of course, every simplicial complex canonically gives rise to a simplicial set.
You can also apply this logic to the homotopy (using that geometric realization preserves products) and slightly reorder the proof. It then immediately reduces to proving that any map $\Delta^n\rightarrow|\mathrm{Sing}(X)|$ taking $\partial\Delta^n$ to the (implicit) basepoint is homotopic to the geometric realization of some simplicial map from a subdivision of the $n$-simplex to $\mathrm{Sing}(X)$ taking the induced subdivision of $\partial\Delta^n$ to the $0$-simplex giving the basepoint.
